# Meshes created from code don't have a position unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, position

So, I tried to create a grid so that I can instantiate objects on it. I check for the position of said hit object (one of the squares I created) and then set the instantiated object to that position. Problem is, the squares I created with code don't have a position and are all set to 0, 0, 0.

````
    {
        GameObject tileObject = new GameObject(string.Format("{0}, {1}", x, y));
        tileObject.transform.parent = transform;

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        tileObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        tileObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = tileMaterial;

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[4];
        vertices[0] = new Vector3(x * tileSize, 0, y * tileSize);
        vertices[1] = new Vector3(x * tileSize, 0, (y +1) * tileSize);
        vertices[2] = new Vector3((x +1) * tileSize, 0, y * tileSize);
        vertices[3] = new Vector3((x +1) * tileSize, 0, (y +1) * tileSize);

        int[] tris = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = tris;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();

        tileObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Tile");
        tileObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

        //var xPos = Mathf.Round(x);
        //var yPos = Mathf.Round(y);

        //tileObject.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos , 0f, yPos);

        return tileObject;
    }```
````

Comment: Well the objects themselves you create are never set to any position ... Only their vertices ... If you need the positions as well then rather set the vertices always equal (local) and rather move the tiles to according positions via transform .. I guess your commented code did this

Comment: derHugo, yes it kinda did. It moved them further apart because it was the vertices position + moving them separately because I do not know how to move them separately and create the vertices always equal as you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said your issue is that you leave all tiles on the position `0,0,0` and only set their vertices to the desired world space positions.

You would rather want to keep your vertices local like e.g.

```
// I would use the offset of -0.5f so the mesh is centered at the transform pivot
// Also no need to recreate the arrays everytime, you can simply reference the same ones
private readonly Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[4]
{
    new Vector3(-0.5f, 0, -0.5f);
    new Vector3(-0.5f, 0, 0.5f);
    new Vector3(0.5f, 0, -0.5f);
    new Vector3(0.5f, 0, 0.5f);
};

private readonly int[] tris = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };
```

and then in your method do

```
GameObject tileObject = new GameObject($"{x},{y}");
tileObject.transform.parent = transform;
tileObject.localScale = new Vector3 (tileSize, 1, tileSize);
tileObject.localPosition = new Vector3(x * tileSize, 0, y * tileSize);
```

The latter depends of course on your needs. Actually I would prefer to have the tiles also centered around the grid object so something like e.g.

```
// The "-0.5f" is for centering the tile itself correctly 
// The "-gridWith/2f" makes the entire grid centered around the parent
tileObject.localPosition = new Vector3((x - 0.5f - gridWidth/2f) * tileSize, 0, (y - 0.5f - gridHeight/2f) * tileSize);
```

---

In order to later find out which tile you are standing on (e.g. via raycasts, collisions, etc) I would then rather use a dedicated component and simply tell it it's coordinates like e.g.

```
// Note that Tile is a built-in type so you would want to avoid confusion
public class MyTile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2Int GridPosition;
}
```

and then while generating your grid you would simply add

```
var tile = tileObject.AddComponent<MyTile>();
tile.GridPosition = new Vector2Int(x,y);
```

while you can still also access its `transform.position` to get the actual world space center of the tiles

Comment: Thanks a lot @derHugo! It helped me greatly, I now have a grid and each square has a position. The only problem I have is that the squares material that is currently being hovered over doesn't change but it did before. I am using render objects for it, when the raycast hits the object it changes the layer from "tile" to "hover". Which it does, but it does not change the material. https://ibb.co/9Txvq46